# How do I access Android STK Menu using APK?

Tags: android, apk, sim-card, sim-toolkit

I would like to access the SIM menus on an Android phone using STK.

I am trying to write an APK that shows the SIM Menus and perform operations on it. However, since the software would be used by users, replacing the OS core modules may not be an option.

How can I do this?

Comment: I am looking for the same solution. Do you find any solution? If yes, then please share.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

This is, unfortunately, not possible. SimToolkit applications are protected from use by other applications because they could incur charges for the user or alter his connectivity state without his knowledge or consent.

The SimToolkit application (which is signed by the manufacturer or mobile operator so that it has special privileges) is the only application which is permitted to communicate with the STK application on the SIM card.

Comment: Where can i learn for about programming for Android STK. Did not found much resource on google.

Comment: Completely not possible? Even after rooting?

Answer (score 1):

The STK as in Sim-Tool-Kit, is actually available in the source code for AOSP.

It can be found under `packages/apps/Stk`, so it would be a matter of taking the source from that and modify to suit your needs.

Comment: You can modify it all you want, but you'll never get it to run on a standard non-rooted consumer device. STK must run with the privileged user ID of the phone.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the stk app from here, https://goo.im/devs/playfulgod/misc/Stk.apk/ and copied it to system/app , modified the permissions to rw-r--r-- and rebooted. Voila! Stk appeared on the app drawer and it's working. Using Paranoid android 4.5-Beta2