# How To Modify SIM Application Toolkit(STK) Rooted Mobile

Tags: android, sim-toolkit

Dear Android Developers,

I want to modify Sim toolkit application according to client requirement e.g app checks balance automatically.Manually Our Currier allow this feature in Sim toolkit.
I did a lot of search how i can accomplish this but could not get any where.

what i did so far is

1-Rooted My Device.

Got Hint From This Question
[How do I access Android STK Menu using APK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227732/android-stk-menu-using-apk)

2-Downloaded the source code of STK from github https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_stk

3-Remove all errors of project by building and setting internal API.
http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/

when i am running this project getting this 
**error**

**Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE**

I checked all stackoverflow questions e.g [INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE while using shared user id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205159/install-failed-shared-user-incompatible-while-using-shared-user-id)

but not found any solution.
Please help me what i am doing wrong.my direction is wrong or not?
Please gave any suggestion any thing which can gave me idea.

Thankx in advance.Sorry for my English i am new developer.

Comment: Using a shared user id requires that you sign the apk with the same certificate as that used to sign whatever existing components you are sharing with.  Since that is a closely held secret of the device vendor, you can't do that.  You might be able to re-sign the whole thing though.  As you are finding, it's hard to make "just a little" change in Android - it's really intended with the idea that 3rd parties will stick to the application APIs, and vendors will do a full system build from source.

Comment: Sir @ChrisStratton this app will not be publicly launched.I need to do custom app only on one device if there is any way i can do this please gave me idea what to do.I don't have any idea i just want to accomplish this.please help thankx

Comment: If this is very difficult solution can i make other application which Can communicate with sim and perform actions.?any help

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in one of the comments, the error is due to application being signed with a different certificate. This certificate dependency can be removed by changing the package names in the application. Because each java package belongs to the certificate with which it is signed.

Answer (score 0):

The SIM Application Toolkit(STK) shares the same user id as Phone, as it runs in phone process. So unless you get the platform signature of Your device, You can't run the Stk.

Since you have rooted, you may access the phone interface directly,remove android:sharedUserId="android.uid.phone" from manifest.xml