# com.android.internal.telephony.cat.Duration not found in android

Tags: android, sim-toolkit

I am a new android developer. I want to develop an app which can access SIM Tool Kit in android mobile. But I haven't found the exact solution online. I found 2 examples:

- https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_stk
- http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.4.2_r1/com/android/stk/StkLauncherActivity.java?av=f

when I import `com.android.internal.telephony.cat.Duration` class in ADT, it does not find it.

I also found this class here:

- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/e005c3c44109c9b4a8d25f05e8b7133d5ef55ead/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/cat/

But I am not able use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to google a little bit, you'd find out that this is impossible.

1. `com.android.internal.telephony.cat.Duration` has an `@hide` annotation that means it's not accesible through the SDK
2. The whole `internal` package is meant to be *internal*, i.e. used by android not by developers.
3. [STK itself is not accessible to external apps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16447150/3249477)

However there's also reflection which *may* be used to access hidden methods. Though I didn't bother to try, [this](https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/) might help.