# Open menu of the Sim tool kit

Tags: android, gsm, sim-toolkit

I want my app to open sim card toolkit so that a user can make payments via mobile provided in the sim toolkit application
Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android STK Menu using APK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227732/android-stk-menu-using-apk)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this will launch it on some devices:

```
Intent simToolKitLaunchIntent = getContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.stk");
if(simToolKitLaunchIntent != null) {
    startActivity(simToolKitLaunchIntent);
}
```

Comment: And what if i want to open a dialogue that overlays the sim-toolkit. Like for instance to give the user directions on how to perform certain actions

Answer (score 0):

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.stk");
            if (intent != null){
                startActivity(intent);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NO SIM CARD FOUND",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
          
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please try this it will work fine... Also please note if the device will have no SIM CARD the Toast will be displayed. My English though (*_*)